# RecyclerView animation issue Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have added an animation to the recyclerview to show the below transition.

When I long press on an item it shows the radio button and the item card moves to the right. The issue is that after the initial selection when ever I click or select other items, item6 and the items below animates again.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can fix this.

[image]

ListAdapter.kt:

```
class ListItemAdapter(private val values: List<PlaceholderContent.PlaceholderItem>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var itemClick: OnItemClick
    private var selectedIndex: Int = -1
    private var selectedItems: SparseBooleanArray = SparseBooleanArray()
    private var isActive: Boolean = false
    private var activateAnimation: Boolean = false

    fun setItemClick(itemClick: OnItemClick) {
        this.itemClick = itemClick
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ListItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_item,
            parent,
            false
        )
        return ItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.apply {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_number).text = values[position].id
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.content).text = values[position].content
        }

        holder.itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.list_item).setOnClickListener {
            itemClick.onItemClick(values[position], position)
        }

        holder.itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.list_item).setOnLongClickListener {
            itemClick.onLongPress(values[position], position)
            true
        }

        toggleIcon(holder, position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return values.size
    }
    
    private fun itemTransition(holder: ItemViewHolder){
        val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item), View.TRANSLATION_X, 150f)
        animator.start()
    }

    private fun itemTransitionBack(holder: ItemViewHolder){
        val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item), View.TRANSLATION_X, 0f)
        animator.start()
    }


    fun toggleIcon(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int){
        val checkBox = holder.itemView.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.is_selected)
        if(selectedItems.get(position, false)){
            checkBox.isGone = false
            checkBox.isChecked = true
        }
        else{
            checkBox.isGone = true
            checkBox.isChecked = false
        }
        if(isActive) checkBox.isGone = false

        if(activateAnimation){
            itemTransition(holder)
        }
        else
            itemTransitionBack(holder)

        if(selectedIndex == position) selectedIndex = - 1
    }

    fun selectedItemCount() = selectedItems.size()

    fun toggleSelection(position: Int){

        selectedIndex = position
        if (selectedItems.get(position, false)){
            selectedItems.delete(position)
        }else {
            selectedItems.put(position, true)
        }
        notifyItemChanged(position)

        isActive = selectedItems.isNotEmpty()
        activateAnimation = selectedItems.isNotEmpty()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun clearSelection(){
        selectedItems.clear()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    interface OnItemClick {
        fun onItemClick(item: PlaceholderContent.PlaceholderItem, position: Int)
        fun onLongPress(item: PlaceholderContent.PlaceholderItem, position: Int)
    }

    inner class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    }

}
```

ItemFragment.kt

```
adapter = ListItemAdapter(PlaceholderContent.ITEMS)
val recyclerViewList = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list)
recyclerViewList.adapter = adapter
recyclerViewList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
val myHelper = ItemTouchHelper(myCallback)
myHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewList)

adapter.setItemClick(object : ListItemAdapter.OnItemClick{
    override fun onItemClick(
        item: PlaceholderContent.PlaceholderItem,
        position: Int
    ) {
        if(adapter.selectedItemCount() > 0)
            toggleSelection(position)
    }

    override fun onLongPress(
        item: PlaceholderContent.PlaceholderItem,
        position: Int
    ) {
        toggleSelection(position)
    }

})

private fun toggleSelection(position: Int){
    adapter.toggleSelection(position)
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why did you use both ```notifyItemChanged``` with ```notifyDataSetChanged``` inside ```toggleSelection(position: Int)``` method? Both of them are calling each time with updating the status of single item. Did you checked removing that part? let me know

Comment: The reason for using notifyDataSetChanged() is to notify all the items that they should show checkbox for selection. Then after all check-boxes are visible in the whole recyclerview item and the user press a random item. I need to notify that item to show the checkbox is selected, for that purpose I use notifyItemChanged.

Comment: But these two statements are forcing every item to ve updated but your view holder currently holding 5 items normally, you should only update the item position which is updating its view. Calling notifyDataSetChanged becomes an expensive statement for this solution. If you have this project on GitHub, share the GitHub public link so that I can check it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside your `adapter.toggleSelection(position)`, regardless of whether this position was updated or not, this is re-binding all the visible views (and running the animations again).

#### Update

As stated in the comments, the reason why the 6th item is animated is likely due to the default ViewPool that the RecyclerView keeps (5 items). The 6th view is not part of that so it gets re-bound, re-displayed, and... re-animated.

What I would do is:

1. Could I get rid of the `notifyDataSetChanged()`? Why are you calling that?
2. Could I leverage [RecyclerView-Selection](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/package-summary) since it's a Google library and what they suggest we use? It would have the benefit of less "custom" code.

Other than this, you could try to increase the [RecycledViewPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool) as suggested by [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9241978/pawel) in the comments. Keep in mind this would likely be considered a *code smell* because different resolution, densities, screen sizes, etc., may affect how this behaves at runtime; this would be flaky and prone to fail, but depending on your particular use-case, may allow you go *get away with it* for now.

Comment: Can you explain why the animation is only running after item6 and below after the initial selection?

Comment: I cannot without running it and debugging, but my guess is the adapter thinks/figures those ViewHolders are already in the correct state after the call to notifyDataSetChanged is dispatched. Remember it's all asynchronous in a way.

Comment: Can you suggest any possible solutions that I could make to fix this?

Comment: This is one of those problems where it's hard to figure it out without having the project in front/running/trying 20000 things. My 1st suggestion is: can you get rid of the `notifyDataSetChanged`? Could [the RecyclerView-Selection](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/package-summary) class from Google help you in using a "less custom" solution? (just tossing ideas).

Comment: [RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool) has size of 5 by default, you can probably do a crude fix by increasing that amount. You can also try to setHasStableIds and override getItemId for the adapter.

Comment: Yeah, what ^ said. I mean, chances are the 5st viewholders are not changed and cached, so they receive no dispatched changes from the adapter.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini, The reason why I used notifyDataSetChanged() is to show checkboxes in each item when one item is selected. So even though I use recyclerview-selection, I would have to use notifyDataSetChanged() again right?, to show all the checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

You can override `getItemViewType(int position)` this will returning the id of the view which is always unique.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

**or**

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(final int position) {
    return R.layout.fragment_item;
}
```

Since the Android system stores a static reference to each layout as an Integer in the “R” (resources) class, we can simply return the layout resource id to be used in the `onCreateViewHolder()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hack, but have you consider using?

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

If the list would not be large and if it solves the issue, it can be used as a quick solution.

Comment: I can't use this, the list is really large.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **position** try & use **holder.getAdapterPosition(**) same for all the click action your are performing in to the bind method of the adapter,

```
holder.itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.list_item).setOnClickListener {
            itemClick.onItemClick(values[position], holder.getAdapterPosition())
        }

        holder.itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.list_item).setOnLongClickListener {
            itemClick.onLongPress(values[position], holder.getAdapterPosition())
            true
        }

        toggleIcon(holder, holder.getAdapterPosition())
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to work. Can you share your thoughts behind this approach?

Comment: Please go through this blog content https://proandroiddev.com/difference-between-position-getadapterposition-and-getlayoutposition-in-recyclerview-80279a2711d1